# how to bypass j2me sign

Tags: java-me, sign

j2me jar application asks user for permission to make a photo and etc. is there a free way to bypass this? or is there a free webcam aplication for mobile phones?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

The only way to bypass these kinds of warnings is to sign your application with an appropriate security certificate, which is normally not free and varies by device manufacturer and/or wireless carrier. Read [Java ME Signing For Dummies](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/Java_ME_signing_for_dummies) for more information.

Comment: i found some certificate for sonyericsson called "Halmer", mybe there is something for nokia?

Comment: any free certificates for nokia?